# Div with content inside a perfect circle

Tags: css

I'm trying to replicate the
following mockup
[image]
just to practice to place a square inside the circle but this is as close as I can get,
[image]
I tried using JS but just get weird looking circles.
This is my code

Index.html

```css
    .action-selection {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .action {
      height: auto;
      flex: 0 1 30%;
      border-radius: 100%;
      border: 2px solid orange;
      text-align:center;  
    }

    .action img {
      width: 30px;
    }

    .action div {
      border: 2px dashed black;
      height : auto;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="action-selection">
        <div class="action">
          <div><img src="img/phone.png"><p>I'm already lincenced and I want to join BeUrban</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="action">
          <div>
            <img src="img/phone.png"><p>I'm licensed but I'd like to know more about BeUrban</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="action">
          <div>
            <img src="img/phone.png"><p>I'm ready to start my career with BeUrban</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of little elements here. First of all, don't be afraid to use multiple wrapping divs when you have a lot of behaviors to handle rather than trying to put too many responsibilities on too few elements.

- You already have the width set using flex-basis.
- To make the circles have a fixed 1:1 width to height ratio you can use 50% border, height of 0, and padding-top 100%. That last bit is tricky but padding top or bottom with a percentage is a percentage of the width.
- To center the squares, use another div with absolute position, top 50% and left 50% and then translate:transform( -50%, -50% ). The translate values are a percentage of the element itself and the top and left positioning percentages are percentages of the parent.
- To add padding to the square without affecting it's size, use box-sizing: border-box
- Finally, I used width and height of 72% to get the squares to contact the circles. That's pretty close to the ( square root of 2 ) / 2 * 100% which is 70.7% but it worked for me with your border thicknesses.

```css
.action-selection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.action {
  flex: 0 1 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

.action img {
  width: 30px;
}

.action__container-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.action__content-square {
  border: 2px dashed black;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
  width: 72%;
  height: 72%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="action-selection">
  <div class="action">
    <div class="action__container-circle">
      <div class="action__content-square">
        <img src="img/phone.png">
        <p>I'm already lincenced and I want to join BeUrban</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <div class="action__container-circle">
      <div class="action__content-square">
        <img src="img/phone.png">
        <p>I'm licensed but I'd like to know more about BeUrban</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <div class="action__container-circle">
      <div class="action__content-square">
        <img src="img/phone.png">
        <p>I'm ready to start my career with BeUrban</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no reason to add more wrappers. He already had enough to do the job

Comment: I know that this is an opinion based thing and that there is always more than one way to do things, but the reason I added wrappers is for more easily readable, maintainable code. `.action div` is objectively worse than a descriptive class like `action__circle` but @Scrimothy is right that you can get this look without more wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.action-selection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.action {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.action img {
  width: 30px;
}

.action div {
  border: 2px dashed black;
  /* height: auto; */
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 65%;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="action-selection">
  <div class="action">
    <div><img src="img/phone.png">
      <p>I'm already lincenced and I want to join BeUrban</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <div>
      <img src="img/phone.png">
      <p>I'm licensed but I'd like to know more about BeUrban</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <div>
      <img src="img/phone.png">
      <p>I'm ready to start my career with BeUrban</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Getting better. Your "squares" are 150 * 130 at the full snippet size now.

Answer (score 0):

The trick with creating perfect circles that are dependent on the viewport width is to use `width` and the same value for `padding-top`. Padding percentage, is based on width, whereas if you used a height percentage, that would be based on the height of the parent.

In this case, if you're basically using `width: 30%` then you'd use `padding-top: 30%`, and then set the content to `position: absolute` and then just center it inside the relatively positioned circle. You'll likely have to fiddle around with the exact width/height combo that you want, but this'll get you the perfect circle you're looking for.

**Note** there's no way though CSS only to calculate the exact points where the internal square/rectangle should meet the external circle. That would require more complex math than what CSS `calc` can do, because you'd have to determine that based on the height of the content inside the rectangle and adjust your width from there.

```css
.action-selection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.action {
  height: auto;
  flex: 0 1 30%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  text-align:center;  
  display: flex;
}

.action img {
  width: 30px;
}

.action div {
  border: 2px dashed black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="action-selection">
    <div class="action">
      <div><img src="img/phone.png"><p>I'm already lincenced and I want to join BeUrban</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
      <div>
        <img src="img/phone.png"><p>I'm licensed but I'd like to know more about BeUrban</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
      <div>
        <img src="img/phone.png"><p>I'm ready to start my career with BeUrban</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your dashed borders should be squares that contact the circles

Comment: @JasonB As mentioned in my answer, you have 3 options: 1. hard-code the points of the squares like you did at 72% and then decide what to do with the overflow, 2. choose a close proximity assuming that this is just an experiment and the goal is more than just "square-touching-circle", 3. use javascript to calculate the exact height and width the square should be based on the circle and the content.

Answer (score -1):

hey check this please add the code in your page then it will look as per your requirement.

```css
.action-selection {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.action {
    border: 2px solid orange;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius:100%;
}
.action div {
    border: 2px dashed black;
    height: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 52px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.action img {
    width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="action-selection">
    <div class="action">
      <div><img src="img/phone.png"><p>I'm already lincenced and I want to join BeUrban</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
      <div>
        <img src="img/phone.png"><p>I'm licensed but I'd like to know more about BeUrban</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
      <div>
        <img src="img/phone.png"><p>I'm ready to start my career with BeUrban</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```